# Java library for opening PDF with text, images, & formatting?

Tags: java, pdf

I'm developing a software (mac & pc) for opening & annotating PDFs for presentations.  I need help finding a Java library that can assist with opening an external PDF, that will not just open the text, but the images & formatting as well. Anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

There's a library called [iText](http://www.itextpdf.com/) that does most things you will need for PDF. I only know it because it was part of an application I modified, so I don't have anything to compare it against.

I did find some of its behavior non-intuitive, so you may want to look around still.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK iText is to generate and manipulate PDF files. If you want to open and view PDFs use http://pdfbox.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

Most Java libraries will let you access the low level objects. Your exact requirement is quite vague what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: the exact requirements are to open an external pdf and be able to support the images and formatting/annotations on the PDF. Right now, I think iText is not supporting the images & formatting.